# Get values of latest year and all its months in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, drop-duplicates

Below is the Raw Data.

```
Event       Month       Year
Event1      January     2012
Event1      February    2013
Event1      March       2014
Event1      April       2017
Event1      May         2017
Event1      June        2017
Event2      May         2018
Event2      May         2019
Event3      February    2012
Event3      March       2012
Event3      April       2012
```

- Event1 latest year is 2017 so month should be April, May, June.
- Event2 latest year is 2019 so month should be May.
- Event3 latest year is 2012 so month should be February, March, April.

Output Should be : -

```
Event       Month       Year
Event1      April       2017
Event1      May         2017
Event1      June        2017
Event2      May         2019
Event3      February    2012
Event3      March       2012
Event3      April       2012
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) the latest year per group and use it to slice:

```
out = df[df['Year'].eq(df.groupby('Event')['Year'].transform('max'))]
```

output:

```
     Event     Month  Year
3   Event1     April  2017
4   Event1       May  2017
5   Event1      June  2017
7   Event2       May  2019
8   Event3  February  2012
9   Event3     March  2012
10  Event3     April  2012
```